# Mypy: got "function", expected "Callable[..., Any]"

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

```py
import glob
from typing import Callable, List


def fun1(b: str) -> List[str]:
    return ["a", "b"] + [b]


def fun(a: str) -> Callable:
    return fun1 if a == "hello" else glob.glob
```

Running mypy on this file gives:

```py
error: Incompatible return value type (got "function", expected "Callable[..., Any]")  [return-value]
```

but I thought a function was a Callable? This seems specific to `glob.glob` since if I simply return `fun1` then the error goes away.

**EDIT**:

Opened an [issue on github](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/12053).

Comment: `glob.glob` has a mandatory parameter, `fun1` doesn't. Because either could be returned, the caller of `fun` can't know (except by re-implementing the logic) whether to pass an argument when using the result.

Comment: That actually looks like a bug in mypy. While your code example seems weird, your annotations are correct.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, since they are not using a binding TypeVar, Callable should catch any callable regardless of consistency of args and return value.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel ok, I've changed my MRE to be actually more like what I use, which still gives the same error

Comment: It does look like a bug in mypy, indeed. That error is returned when the two functions have "incompatible" signatures (e.g. different number of positional arguments). This seems to include keyword-only parameters, but still it counts only the number of parameters not their names (which doesn't really make sense). So it's probably worth submitting a bug report to mypy. In the meantime, this can be fixed by [`cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast)ing *both* functions to `Callable` like so: `return cast(Callable, fun1) if a == "hello" else cast(Callable, glob.glob)`.

Comment: This is probably a result of [MyPy#4134](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/4134).

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a `mypy` limit with `if else` ternary operator, this indeed seems to work:

```
import glob
from typing import Callable, List


def fun1(b: str) -> List[str]:
    return ["a", "b"] + [b]


def fun(a: str) -> Callable:
    if a == "hello":
        return fun1
    else:
        return glob.glob
```